# Facebook Canvas App Saving Flash Vars to Db

Tags: flash, facebook, sdk, fbml, actionscript-2

I have made a flash game for facebook. All happened right expect when I am saving score in my Db. I had sended vars from flash to php , which I think is not working:

//Here is how i am sending vars from flash

loadVariablesNum("highscore.php?uid="+iduser+"&usc="+score, 0);

I had check it on my localhost its working perfectly. But when I upload same on facebook it doesnot work out.

I had used Php SDK 3 and havenot used fbml.

embeded flash with Object and Embed tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full path to the php file rather than a relative path. Also, try replacing `&` with `%26`